# iOS Firebase - how to force data reads to happen sequentially?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to use multiple snapshots to get info that I need for my code. The problem is that sometimes they don't execute in the order that I need them to. Right now I'm nesting them like this:

```
 _ = ref.child("users").child(self.userKey).child("name").observeSingleEvent(of: FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

   //execute block 1
   let argToQuery2 = snapshot.value as! String

         _ = ref.child("users").child(argToQuery2).child("job").observeSingleEvent(of: FIRDataEventType.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            //execute block2 
......
     })
})
```

But as I said I'm finding that block 1 doesn't always execute before block2, and I need the information from block 1 to complete block 2. How can I force these queries to happen sequentially? If I only had two queries I would try using a boolean to see if the first block had finished or not, but in my actual code I have 5+ of these nested.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried with NSOperationQueue ? You can set dependency for your operations using NSOperationQueue.

Comment: I will look into this, thanks